# JS Как отслеживать изменение переменной?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не могу найти понятного метода для отслеживания значений в переменных. Условно у меня есть две переменных, по дефолту там значения `false`, но когда в обоих будет `true` мне нужно чтобы выполнилось какое-то действие. Например, как в этом примере нужно отследить значения и включить кнопку.

```js
let a = false;
let b = false;

// Проверяю перый чек бокс и меняю значение
$('#check_1').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
        a = true;
    }else{
        a = false;
    }
});

// Проверяю второй чек бокс и меняю значение
$('#check_2').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
        b = true;
    }else{
        b = false;
    }
});

//Теперь как то нужно првоерить значение в переменных a и b и включить кнопку.
if (a == true && b == true) {
  $('#btn_send').attr('disabled', false);
} else {
  $('#btn_send').attr('disabled', true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id='btn_send' disabled>Send</button>
<p><input id='check_1' type='checkbox'>Check 1</p>
<p><input id='check_2' type='checkbox'>Check 2</p>
```

Comment: выносишь проверку в функцию и вызываешь ее каждый раз, когда меняешь переменую

Comment: @Grundy Ну почему я такой не сообразительный =(( Спасибо большое!

Comment: Еще я бы убрал ваши `if ... else` и заменил бы на `a = $(this).prop('checked')`. И `$('#btn_send').attr('disabled', !(a == true && b == true));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант просто делать вызов функции, содержащей в себе ваше условие.

Например так:

```js
let a = false;
let b = false;

// Проверяю перый чек бокс и меняю значение
$('#check_1').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
        a = true;
    }else{
        a = false;
    }
    checkIfBothTrue();
});

// Проверяю второй чек бокс и меняю значение
$('#check_2').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
        b = true;
    }else{
        b = false;
    }
    checkIfBothTrue();
});

//Теперь как то нужно првоерить значение в переменных a и b и включить кнопку.
function checkIfBothTrue() {
  if (a == true && b == true) {
    $('#btn_send').attr('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('#btn_send').attr('disabled', true);
  }
}
```

```html
<button id='btn_send' disabled>Send</button>
<p><input id='check_1' type='checkbox'>Check 1</p>
<p><input id='check_2' type='checkbox'>Check 2</p>
```